# Helping my son find his unknown biological father

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, gedmatch.com

My son's biological father and his family is unknown. Both my son and I took Ancestry DNA tests. Then I went through his matches for "shared matches" - if I didn't show up, I assumed the match was from his paternal side. Is this assumption correct?

Now we've both uploaded our raw data to GEDmatch and FTDNA. Is there a one-to-many test for my son's dna that excludes matches to me?

Is there some other DNA test we should do?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is not correct. There are four buckets with the matches:
- matches from maternal line
- matches from paternal line
- matches from BOTH lines
- matches which are not present in mother's test and in father's test

The last may be matches with IBS - Identical-by-state segments of DNA, not IBD (Identical-by-descent). So they are false-positive. It is not uncommon to have such.

```
Is there a one-to-many test for my son's dna that excludes matches to me?
```

Please use the tool called "People who match one or both of 2 kits Updated". It splits matches into three categories: common matches, matches only in one kit and matches only in another kit.